# Issue w. AWSDevTools was not loaded (git aws.push)

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

On Windows, I got AWSDevTools working fine the other day. I'm new to using Elastic Beanstalk, I got eb CLI tools setup on my computer the other day. I was able to deploy he Hello World tutorial, but after a restart I get the following error:

> Import-Module : The specified module 'AWSDevTools' was not loaded
>   because no valid module file was found in any module directory. At
>   line:1 char:18
>   + & { Import-Module <<<<  AWSDevTools; $e, $c = Get-Options $args; Invoke-AWSElasticBeanstalkPush $e $c }
>       + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (AWSDevTools:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
>
> The term 'Get-Options' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the  spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. At line:1 char:52
>   + & { Import-Module AWSDevTools; $e, $c = Get-Options <<<<  $args; Invoke-AWSElasticBeanstalkPush $e $c }
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Options:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>
> The term 'Invoke-AWSElasticBeanstalkPush' is not recognized as the
>   name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable  program. Check
>   the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
>   path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:90
>   + & { Import-Module AWSDevTools; $e, $c = Get-Options $args; Invoke-AWSElasticBeanstalkPush <<<<  $e $c }
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-AWSElasticBeanstalkPush:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

**-EDIT-**

It seems that I have to run PowerShell as a Administrator... Not entirely sure why this is, on my Windows 7 Ultimate laptop I am able to use AWSDevTools modules in PowerShell without heighten permissions but on Windows 8.1 Preview I have too... But it worked the other day?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the AWSDevTools-OneTimeSetup.bat file.  It is located in the tool kit: AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/AWSDevTools/Windows/AWSDevTools-OneTimeSetup.bat

If you don't have the toolkit, you can download it here: http://aws.amazon.com/code/6752709412171743